# How to add SMB as Bonjour Service in Windows

Tags: java, windows, bonjour, mdns, dns-sd

I have a Windows 10 machine on my network acting as a File Server, one of the clients to that sever is a Mac. I know for example that making a Samba share in Linux also creates an mDNS entry that makes it instantly visible to my Mac machine in Finder. After some research I have been able to use Bonjour installed on Windows to advertise my SMB share to MacOS via Bonjour.

By running dns-sd command in CMD with the following command:

> dns-sd -R HOSTNAME _smb._tcp local 445

The computer/share appears in Finder.

How ever this continues to run in the CMD window, meaning i have to leave the CMD window doing this to continue broadcasting the service via Bonjour. The service is registered but not appended or added to anything, once you close that CMD windows or CTRL + C the service stops.

Is there a way I can make it so that Bonjour on system startup broadcasts this service? It's been hard to find much documentation of how if at all possible to do this on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this as you suggested, as I am Trying to  advertise a _uscan._tcp service , but all I get is

```
no main manifest attribute, in dns_sd.jar
```

Also worth mentioning that if you run the Bonjour SDK for windows, it installs an app in control panel to advertise SMB. It however  does not allow advertising other services. I need to figure out how I can advertise _uscan._tcp on windows 10!

Comment: I know it’s been ages since I posted this but since I am revisiting this due to some issues I realised recently DN-SD is not the jar rather it is the dns-sd installed in System32.